# trying to fetch data from newsapi.org but ending up with 403 error, paramType 2048 not found etc

Tags: json, api, android-studio, url

NetworkUtilities.java

public class NetworkUtilities {

```
private static final String TAG = NetworkUtilities.class.getSimpleName();

public static URL createUrl(String stringUrl){
    URL url = null;
    try{
        url = new URL(stringUrl);
    }catch (MalformedURLException e){
        Log.v(TAG, "Problem building the Url");
    }
    return url;
}


public static String httpRequest(URL url) throws IOException{
    String jsonResponse = "";
    if(url ==null){
        Log.v(TAG, "Url is null");
        return jsonResponse;
    }
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try{
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpURLConnection.connect();

        if(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == 200){
            inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
        }
        else{
            Log.e(TAG, "Error response code" + httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.v(TAG, "Problem retrieving the json result", e);
    }finally {
        if(httpURLConnection != null){
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if(inputStream != null){
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    return jsonResponse;
}

private static String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    if(inputStream != null){
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(in);
        String line = bf.readLine();
        while(line != null){
            output.append(line);
            line = bf.readLine();
        }
    }
    return output.toString();
}

public static List<String> extractFromJson(String jsonResponse){
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(jsonResponse)){
        return null;
    }
     List<String> newsStories = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        JSONObject baseObj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        JSONArray articlesArray = baseObj.getJSONArray("data");
        for(int i=0;i<articlesArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject currentArticle = articlesArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject source = currentArticle.getJSONObject("source");
            String sourceName = source.getString("name");
            String title = currentArticle.getString("title");
            String description = currentArticle.getString("description");
            String newsStory = "Source" + sourceName + "/n" + title + "/n" + description;
            newsStories.add(newsStory);
        }
    }catch (JSONException e){
        Log.e(TAG, " Problem parsing the json string", e);
    }
    return newsStories;
}
```

NewsAdapter.java

public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {

```
private Context mContext;
private List<String> mNewsArticles;
NewsAdapter(Context context){
    mContext = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater
            .from(mContext)
            .inflate(R.layout.news_list_item,parent, false);
    view.setFocusable(true);
    return new NewsViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder( NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String currentArticle = mNewsArticles.get(position);
    holder.mTextView.setText(currentArticle);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(mNewsArticles != null){
        return mNewsArticles.size();
    }
    return 0;
}


public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    final TextView mTextView;

    public NewsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "position :" + getLayoutPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
 public void setNewsData(List<String> newsData){
    mNewsArticles = newsData;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private NewsAdapter mNewsAdapter;
private static final String BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=13f428d687714c33a24f34ad6c5***87";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
        new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mNewsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(this);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mNewsAdapter);

new FetchNewsArticle().execute(BASE_URL);
}

public class FetchNewsArticle extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>>{

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String stringUrl = strings[0];
        URL url = NetworkUtilities.createUrl(stringUrl);
        String json = "";
        try{
            json = NetworkUtilities.httpRequest(url);
            List<String> articles = NetworkUtilities.extractFromJson(json);
            return articles;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v(TAG, "Problem retrieving data");
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> strings) {
        if(strings != null){
         mNewsAdapter.setNewsData(strings);
        }
    }
}
```

Error

W/Zygote: Unable to open libbeluga.so: dlopen failed: library "libbeluga.so" not found.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/xample.newsfee: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View; >computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/xample.newsfee: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
com.example.newsfeed V/NetworkUtilities: **Problem retrieving the json result**

java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to api.mediastack.com not permitted
at com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler$CleartextURLFilter.checkURLPermitted(HttpHandler.java:127)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:462)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
at com.example.newsfeed.Utils.NetworkUtilities.httpRequest(NetworkUtilities.java:49)
at com.example.newsfeed.MainActivity$FetchNewsArticle.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:46)
at com.example.newsfeed.MainActivity$FetchNewsArticle.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:38)
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2021-03-11 22:53:28.124 9391-9391/com.example.newsfeed W/Looper: PerfMonitor looperActivity : package=com.example.newsfeed/.MainActivity time=1ms latency=447ms running=2ms  procState=2 ClientTransaction{ callbacks=[android.app.servertransaction.TopResumedActivityChangeItem] } historyMsgCount=4 (msgIndex=3 wall=87ms seq=3 running=50ms runnable=28ms io=2ms late=6ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=110) (msgIndex=4 wall=356ms seq=4 running=212ms runnable=80ms io=11ms late=91ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=159)
2021-03-11 22:53:28.199 9391-9429/com.example.newsfeed I/AdrenoGLES-0: QUALCOMM build                   : 979eaa0, I11632bc865
Build Date                       : 11/18/20
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.32.02.00
Local Branch                     :
Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.9.1.R1.11.00.00.604.067
Remote Branch                    : NONE
Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2021-03-11 22:53:28.199 9391-9429/com.example.newsfeed I/AdrenoGLES-0: Build Config                     : S P 10.0.6 AArch64
2021-03-11 22:53:28.199 9391-9429/com.example.newsfeed I/AdrenoGLES-0: Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
2021-03-11 22:53:28.213 9391-9429/com.example.newsfeed I/AdrenoGLES-0: PFP: 0x016ee190, ME: 0x00000000
2021-03-11 22:53:28.253 9391-9429/com.example.newsfeed E/LB: fail to open file: No such file or directory

Comment: I am new in Android Development Please help anyone

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be: `java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to api.mediastack.com not permitted`.

Starting from Android 9, clear text http communication is disabled by default.

Check out the official Android [documentation for this](http://the%20official%20Android%20documentation) and also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted) for further information.